# Not Able to Post the Data to Server Using JSONObjectRequest

Tags: java, android

Here is my Method for posting the Data to the Server but couldn't post it.
I have to post the Data to the Server, I'm using JsonObjectRequest is there any another method to post the data, Please help me.

```
 private void postNoticeData() {
    final String noticeTitle = postTitle.getText().toString();
    final String description = postDescription.getText().toString();

    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put(KEY_NOTICE_TITLE, noticeTitle);
    params.put(KEY_NOTICE_DESCRIPTION, description);



    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            URL_DATA,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.i("@school", "Response - " + response);
                    Toast.makeText(AddNoticeAdmin.this.getApplication(), "Added Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    AddNoticeAdmin.this.NavigateToNotice();
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.i("@school", "Error - " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(AddNoticeAdmin.this.getApplication(), "Check your Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

Its Showing the Volley Error please help Me out

Comment: post error log along with a question

Comment: you didn't set `params` to request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the Post Method After the URl As follows:

```
 JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
        URL_DATA, postNotice(),
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

   }
```

The postNotice Method

```
private String postNotice() {
    // Your POJO Class();
    // the Data to be Posted using the PojoClass Object;

    return new Gson().toJson(pojoClassObject);
}
```

Hope so It helps

Comment: Thanks for the Help Sir...Really helped me